# Ubuntu bootloader issue

Tags: boot

I've made Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with Windows 8.1., but after installing Ubuntu everything is working well, but after 1-2 day(s), I don't see my boot option menu after powering on my system; it directly boots into Windows 8.1.

To fix it I ran the following commands in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then everything ran well but after some time I don't see boot option menu after powering on the device.

Is there any permanent solution for this issue?

Comment: In `/etc/default/grub`, is there a non-zero `GRUB_TIMEOUT`?

Comment: Yeah, it is 10.

Comment: What happens when you reboot after you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: i didn't try that & now my system is running well so i cannot give any precise answer at different instances.but anyway thank you for the help but plz let me know the where is the exact problem in the regarding issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's been fixed or not. Give it a few days and see if the issue occurs again.